# Cannot run virtual device on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I don't have HAXM installed on my computer but my virtual devices still used to work even though it's extremely slow. I tried my best to install HAXM but hit dead ends in every try. Anyway, today I was trying to test a part of my project on virtual device and I noticed this on top of my list of virtual devices: `Android Emulator Hypervisor driver for AMD Processor is not installed` and then on the right-hand side(in a link): `Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors`. I clicked on that and after a while it showed this error:

```
Unable to run Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer: Cannot start process, 
the working directory 
'C:\Users\MahirIslam\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver' does 
not exist
```

But I ignored it and cancelled the installation. Then, I tried to run one of my virtual devices and it required me to install the above one, I cancelled it and my virtual device did not start with an error showing(in a popup box) : `Could not start AVD`. I tried installing it and ran into the same error again.

I am running a Windows 10 machine and my virtualization is enabled. My Android Studio is 4.0. But why is this happening? It used to run fine, even though slow, without HAXM or any of the above. And how do i fix it? Any help is really appreciated.